# How to customize django admin search results in many to many fields

Tags: python, django, admin

I trying to filter the list shown when I use the lupe in many to many fields (image bellow).
Maybe a text search would be interesting too.

Any help?

[image: django lupe search result example]
[image: django admin stacked inline example]

Here's the code:

```
class PresentialModuleCourseInline(NestedStackedInline):
    """Module Course Presential Stacked Inline"""
     model = Course.modules.through
     raw_id_fields = ('module_course',)
     extra = 1

     def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(
           module_course__type_course=ModuleCourse.PRESENTIAL)  # Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make filter in `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` (lupe) you need to add a limit_choices_to the widget, it add a query param to filter in popup page like `?type_course=online`

Sample:

```
class PresentialModuleCourseInline(NestedStackedInline):
"""Module Course Presential Stacked Inline"""
model = Course.modules.through
extra = 1
raw_id_fields = ('module_course', )

def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
    field = form.form.base_fields['module_course']
    field.widget.rel.limit_choices_to =\
        {'type_course': ModuleCourse.PRESENTIAL}
    return form
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.model` is not `QuerySet` or a model, use the model directly:

```
class PresentialModuleCourseInline(NestedStackedInline):
     model = Course.modules.through
     raw_id_fields = ('module_course',)
     extra = 1

     def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Course.objects.filter(module_course__type_course=ModuleCourse.PRESENTIAL)
```

For searching set `search_fields` for your `CourseAdmin`:

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('title',)  # your search fields here
```

Comment: How can I use this in a NestedStackedInline?

Comment: It doesn't depend on `NestedStackedInline`. If you set `search_fields` for the `Course` admin page it will be showed also on [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Sjn.png)

Comment: You're alright. The only limitation is set the queryset for this view, but for filters and search this also apply. Thanks!